# How to make inputs display conditionally

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to make some inputs "disappear" from the inputs area when another input is set to false. Has anyone found any way to do this?

EX:

```
stops = input(false, "Use Stop?")

// if stops is set to false, it doesn't make sense to ask the user how far away the stops should be...They //aren't even enabled! SO, for the sake of neatness I would like to see what I can do to make an irrelevant //inputs appear/disappear based on a condition

stopDistance = input(10, "Stop Distance in ticks")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now way to do this. You cannot conditionally display the inputs. If you don't need it then just ignore it.

If you want a clean input section, you may want to use the `inline` parameter so that you can have the checkbox and the numerical input on the same input line.

I would personally do it this way:

```
stops = input(false, "Use Stop?")
stopDistance = input(10, "Stop Distance in ticks")

stops_2 = input(false, "Stop Distance [ticks]", inline="stop")
stopDistance_2 = input(10, "", inline="stop")
```

[image]